# How to properly store a DateTime into a database with Timezone in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My vue Js component is outputting a date in the format below. The component is actually making use of  [FlatPickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/formatting/)

```
2017-03-04T01:23:43.000Z
```

I have done quite abit of research and can see that the ISO time is in the format

```
2021-05-16T08:09:42+0000
```

I.e without the trailing 'Z' and also the seperator is a Z '.' and not a '+'

Will I need something like moment to convert the date into a suitable format to store in Laravel?

My column on my database is a DateTime column.

Comment: Do you really need to manually input the DateTime or is it automatically generated for column like `created_at` or `updated_at`?

Comment: The date is manually generated from users input.
I am using the dates for another column which is start_time.
Within my model I have put 'start_time' as a 'dateTime' in the casts array property

Comment: Try with formatting with [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation)

Comment: Store everything in UTC format and convert to user's timezone on frontend. You can use something like momentjs to convert on frontend.
https://twitter.com/themsaid/status/1351103492367282176

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah how do I store the time as UTC in Laravel? Care to shed some light please?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use carbon to input time directly from the database as you save the rest of the data.

```
  'created_at'    => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
  'updated_at'    => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
``
```